# How do I change the colours of a shape drawn by a VisualStyleRenderer?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gdi+

I have an application that dynamically draws a chart onto a winform.

Both the chart background and the individual chart bars are drawn using a VisualStyleRenderer object:

```
 For Each rect As Rectangle In barRectangles

   Dim renderer As New VisualStyleRenderer (VisualStyleElement.StartPanel.UserPane.Normal)
   renderer.DrawBackground(e.Graphics, rect)
 next
```

this draws a nicely rendered rectangle with full XP visual styles, my question is: how do I change the colours used to draw the shape?

Comment: The colors are determined by the visual styles theme selected by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstylerenderer.aspx) might be helpful.